# Black areas on object

Tags: texturing, uv

I dont know what i can do :(
The opposite sides are always black.
I tried to make a new uv map but nothing happend.
Im new at uv mapping i hope you can help me.
I think i did the uv mapping wrong or something like this.

[image: sample]

Comment: you only have one lamp, that face (and probably the bottom) are in a shadow. Rotate the lamp, and add another.

Comment: Thank you so much , so easy but i was really stupid :)